# Is there a way to find the battery usage of apps on Moto 360?

Tags: battery-life, android-wear, motorola-moto-360

I've been using the Moto 360 for a while now, When I started using it the battery life lasted almost the whole day. After a while of usage with couple of new apps, I noticed that the Moto 360 died even before it was evening. So, Is there a way to find the **battery usage of the apps running on the Motorola Moto 360** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can check **Watch battery usage** 
In **Android Wear** app version 1.3.0:

1. Launch Android Wear
2. Tap **gear icon** in action bar to access Settings screen
3. Under device settings check tap **Moto 360** to access your Moto 360 settings
4. Tap **Watch Battery**

   [image: Watch battery usage]

Answer (score 2):

With the Lollipop update for the Moto 360 and the latest Android Wear app, it is possible. From the Android Wear app, go to the main screen and tap the settings gear. From there there is a "Watch Battery" option that will show you the requested information.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this over an year back itself. There was a neat little app called **Wear Battery Stats** on the Google Play Store.[image]